# AttributeError: module 'theano' has no attribute 'compile'

Tags: python, python-3.x, theano, pymc3

I am using Windows 10, python 3.4, Anaconda distribution and getting this error when importing PyMC3 or Theano. Quick google search did not return anything useful... Anyone has any idea what's going on and how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

```
import pymc3
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "<ipython-input-6-200e74b8195d>", line 1, in <module>
import pymc3
File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 19, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymc3\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from .distributions import *
File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 19, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymc3\distributions\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from . import timeseries
File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 19, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymc3\distributions\timeseries.py", line 1, in <module>
import theano.tensor as tt
File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 19, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\__init__.py", line 124, in <module>
from theano.scan_module import (scan, map, reduce, foldl, foldr, clone,
File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 19, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\scan_module\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
from theano.scan_module import scan_opt
File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 19, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\scan_module\scan_opt.py", line 60, in <module>
from theano import tensor, scalar
File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 19, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
from theano.tensor import nnet  # used for softmax, sigmoid, etc.
File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 19, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\nnet\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from .nnet import (
File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 19, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\nnet\nnet.py", line 32, in <module>
from theano.tensor.nnet.sigm import sigmoid, softplus
File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 19, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\nnet\sigm.py", line 275, in <module>
theano.compile.optdb['uncanonicalize'].register("local_ultra_fast_sigmoid",
AttributeError: module 'theano' has no attribute 'compile
```

Comment: Can you show us what line(s) of code produced this error?

Comment: You probably have a file in your current directory called "theano.py". Rename it.

Comment: Edited with the entire error output...

Comment: Have you fixed your error ? I've got the same issue